# pestudio no longer uploading signatures to VirusTotal

Tags: windows-10, malware-detection

For years, I've used [pestudio](https://www.winitor.com/) to check executables for malware, and recent versions of *pestudio* have included the ability to upload a file signature to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) (VT). However, for the past few weeks, I've been unable to use that feature; any file checked shows, "the file has not been found in the repository," rather than a list of responses from AV engines. Both the current *pestudio*, v. 9.00 and an older one, v. 8.99, which had previously been able to check at VT, fail to get a response.

Samuel Tulach's [VirusTotalUploader](https://github.com/SamuelTulach/VirusTotalUploader) *does* work, sending the file to VT (not just the signature). Uploading files through a browser also works.

My research so far, to no avail:

- Used multiple web-search engines on "pestudio VirusTotal", etc.
- Create a specific Windows Firewall rule allowing *pestudio* to connect in both directions
- Try different versions of *pestudio*
- Try *pestudio* upload from a second PC

Is this feature no longer available because of changes at VT, is there some known recent issue due to Windows Updates (currently at  v. 1903, build 18362.592), could it be due to misconfiguration of the PC's, or does someone have another idea what might be the cause?

BTW, much thanks to Winitor and to VirusTotal for these *excellent* tools to check for malware!!

##### Update

As of 2024, *pestudio* no longer uploads to VirusTotal.

Comment: Can you mark your answer as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few days ago, *pestudio* inexplicably again was able to submit files to VirusTotal. There has been no change on my part, on either PC on which this issue occurred, so I assume the cause was an expired or blocked VirusTotal [API key](https://developers.virustotal.com/v3.0/reference#getting-started) that *pestudio* used.

BTW, I found *pestudio* has a "Lookup online" context menu item that *did* work, even during the time that auto upload failed.

---

##### Update, 06 Feb 2020

As of today, *pestudio* **itself** shows as containing malware on *VirusTotal* by 10 AV engines, including MS *Windows Defender*. **However**, when pestudio.zip and all files in the archive are scanned by Defender, they're given a "clean bill of health," no malware detected. **So... it seems Winitor.com and VirusTotal.com are having a tiff, and I don't mean a Tagged Image File Format interchange. sigh. *Children, please behave.*

---

##### Update Feb 2024

As of 2024, *pestudio* no longer uploads to VirusTotal, just displays the message below, so I've switched to using VirusTotalUploader.

[image: pestudie error msg]